# Jasmine Unit Testing Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jasmine, bower

I'm new to Unit Testing.  I have followed the tutorials and I have everything
configured on node.js via npm.  I have done some describe and it just to get the feel for ho things are set up and my spec runner is fine. The problem I'm trying to get test on controllers figured out but I run in a snag and been trying to figure things out for a while but I continue to get the same error so I thought I would reach out.

I'm trying to do a simple test on a LoginController but I continue to get the same error. I can't point out what I'm doing wrong.  Trying to get over this hurdle.

TypeError: angular.mock.module is not a function:

spec runner index html file.

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
 <head>
<title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="../My Documents/My Website/AngularLogin-
      Registration/js/angular-1.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="../My Documents/My Website/AngularLogin-Registration/js/angular-route-1.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="../bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

<!-- include source files here... -->


<!--<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="../My Documents/My Website/AngularLogin-Registration/js/angular-mock.js"></script>
<script src="../My Documents/My Website/AngularLogin-Registration/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="../My Documents/My Website/AngularLogin-Registration/login/login.controller.js"></script>

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script src="spec/test.js"></script>
```

Here is my test file.

```
describe('LoginController test', function () {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_){
        $controller = _$controller_;
}));
describe('$scope.grade', function() {
      it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', 
       function() {
        var $scope = {};
        var controller = $controller('LoginController', { $scope: $scope });
  $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
  $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
    });
       });
          });
```

Thanking You In Advance
PDH

Comment: your test file looks odd compared to a normal test and the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing).  does `beforeEach(module('app'));` and `beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){` work? I don't think using `angular.mock.` is appropriate for those calls....

Answer (score 0):

Load angular-mocks library in your spec runner html , make sure to load it after angular.js.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

You can also use bower to download the js file instead of the CDN.